# Login Page for SAPUI5 app

Tags: sapui5

I'm building an app that is having a login page initially. I'm trying to create a scenario in which the entered login username and password should be compared with the username and password stored in jsondata.xsjs file (The jsondata.xsjs file is fetching data from hana table implemented at back-end).

But the problem is the jsonModel is not fetching the data of username and password from jsondata.xsjs. In order to verify this, I've set alerts at login button by binding the jsonModel data with a Table in onInit() method. But it is showing #user in alert instead of showing the data present in jsonModel.

Here's the code:

**loginpanel.view.js**

```
sap.ui.jsview("test1.loginpanel", {

getControllerName : function() {
    return "test1.loginpanel";
},

createContent : function(oController) { 


        var box = new sap.m.FlexBox({
            alignItems: sap.m.FlexAlignItems.Stretch,
            items: [
                new sap.m.Label({
                    text: "Voyager",
                    design: sap.m.LabelDesign.Bold
                }),
                new sap.m.Input({
                     id:"username_1",
                    placeholder: "username"
                }),
                new sap.m.Input({
                    id: "password_1",
                    type: sap.m.InputType.Password,
                    placeholder: "password"
                }),
                new sap.m.Button({
                    text: "Login",
                    press: function() {
                     oController.sendForm();
                    }
                })
            ],
            direction: "Column"
        }).setAlignItems("Center").setWidth("100%");

        return box;

                }
          });
```

**loginpanel.controller.js**

```
sap.ui.controller("test1.loginpanel", {

    onInit: function(){
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("https://xxx.hanatrial.ondemand.com/loginpanel/jsondata.xsjs", false);
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel); 

    var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
                 editable: false
             }); 
              oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "username"}),
            template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField("user").bindProperty("value", "USERNAME"),
            sortProperty: "USERNAME",
            editable: false
        }));

      oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "password"}),
            template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField().bindProperty("value", "PASSWORD"),
            sortProperty: "PASSWORD",
            editable: false
        }));  
        oTable.setModel(oModel);
        oTable.bindRows("/UserSet");

   },
  sendForm: function()
 {
    var username = sap.ui.getCore().getElementById("username_1").getValue(); 
    alert("username is "+username);
    var password = sap.ui.getCore().getElementById("password_1").getValue(); 
    alert("password is "+password);
    var username1 = sap.ui.getCore().getElementById("user").getValue(); 
    alert("username is "+username1);
  }
    });
```

**jsondata.xsjs**

```
  var select_all_personals_query = "select * from ADMIN.USER";  
   function close(closables) {  
      var closable;  
      var i;  
      for (i = 0; i < closables.length; i++) {  
                closable = closables[i];  
                if(closable) {  
                          closable.close();  
                }  
      }  
  }  
  function getDataPersonals(){  
      var x1 = {
          UserSet: str
          };
      var dataPersonalsList = [];  
      var connection = $.db.getConnection();  
      var statement = null;  
      var resultSet = null;  
      try{  
                statement = connection.prepareStatement(select_all_personals_query);  
                resultSet = statement.executeQuery();  
                var dataPersonal;  

                while (resultSet.next()) {  
                          dataPersonal = {};  
                          dataPersonal.USERNAME = resultSet.getString(2);  
                          dataPersonal.PASSWORD = resultSet.getString(3);  

                          dataPersonalsList.push(dataPersonal);  
                }  
      } finally {  
                close([resultSet, statement, connection]);  
      }  
 //JSON.stringify(obj);        // '"bar"'
 //JSON.stringify({ x: obj }); // '{"x":"bar"}'          
            var str = JSON.stringify({UserSet: dataPersonalsList});   
     return str;  
 }  
  function doGet() {  
      try{  
                $.response.contentType = "application/json";  
                $.response.setBody(getDataPersonals());             
      }  
      catch(err){  
                $.response.contentType = "text/plain";  
                $.response.setBody("Error while executing query: [" + err.message + "]");  
                $.response.returnCode = 200;  
      }  
}  
doGet();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use `getElementById` but `byId` instead; the former is not a UI5 property

Comment: i used it..but it doesn't make any change. The problem still persists at its same place.

Comment: If you just open https://xxx.hanatrial.ondemand.com/loginpanel/jsondata.xsjs in a browser, does it show the correct data?

Comment: yea..it's working fine..!

Comment: when i do the binding of table in view.js and return its variable to createContent at the end then it shows the json data in table control.

Comment: but i don't want the table in view.js and if i use table in controller.js then it doesn't show any value in alert as well

Comment: IMHO, putting UI logic in a controller is bad design. Also,you're referencing 'user' which isnt found anywhere

Comment: 'user' is the id of first column of table template

Comment: But that's an aggregation of your table... Since ID's should be unique, there is most likely no DOM object with id `user` (you can check that in your browser debugger w/ inspect element). Do the first two alerts give correct results?

Comment: No!!!! Don't built a login function into your app. Leverage the platform to get the user to login instead. Building your own login forms is a recipe for disaster in terms of security, sso, enforcing pw policies etc...

Comment: I also tried default login page to customize using the link [http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-65206/version/3] but I didn't get any idea how can integrate this login page wid my app..so that after login, it should navigate to view of my app @jpenninkhof

Comment: Just launch your app. If it requires authentication it will bring you to the login page. Once the user is logged in, the user will be redirected back to your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My app begins to work When I leverage the SAP HANA platform for login/ logout functionality using the following code inside the press() function on click of button:

```
 press: function(){
$.ajax({url:"/sap/hana/xs/formLogin/token.xsjs",type:"GET",beforeSend:function(e){e.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token","Fetch")},success:function(e,s,o){var n=o.getResponseHeader("X-CSRF-Token");$.ajax({url:"/sap/hana/xs/formLogin/logout.xscfunc",type:"POST",beforeSend:function(e){e.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token",n)},success:function(){sap.m.MessageToast.show("Successfully Logged Out"),window.location.reload()}})}});
}
```

It works fine for login/logout of the application.